# morris.js graph is not rendering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, morris.js

I can't seem to get morris.js graph working in rails, using coffeescript. It does not even appear to be rendering on the page. I have managed to get the tutorial graph rendering, which makes me believe it is an issue with my controller (and that my gem files etc are loaded correctly), but I'm totally lost. My console output is below: [image: Console output]

Coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
      $.get '/scores/index.json', (data) ->
        Morris.Line
          element: $('#myfirstchart')
          data: data
          xkey: 'created_at'
          ykeys: ['scores']
          labels: ['Score']
```

index.html.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="myfirstchart" style="border:2px solid red; height: 200px; width: 100%"></div>
```

scores_controller.rb

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        # Display current users scores in the order of created at descending from most recent. Taking the last 5 scores
        @scores = Score.all
      }
      format.json {
        scores = Score.all
        render :json => scores
      }
    end

  end
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the `<script>` tag should be inside the `<head>` section. In your `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
   <!-- other Rails imports -->
</head>

<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

See [jQuery Get Started](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. The fix was to put the records I wanted into a helper and then call that in the JS to render in the view. Get your helper to show the data in the way Morris requires then you’ll be good.

Inside of a helper:

```
def chart_data
        (1.month.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
        {
            period: date,
            score: Score.where("date(created_at) = ?", date).count,
        }
        end
    end
```

In your view:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", style: "height: 205px", id: "scores-morris", data: {scores: chart_data} %>
```

And finally add your js/coffee script. This is coffee:

```
$ ->
  Morris.Line
    element: 'scores-morris'
    data: $('#scores-morris').data('scores')
    xkey: 'period'
    ykeys: [ 'score' ]
    labels: [ 'SCORE!!!' ]
    hideHover: [ 'auto' ]
```